# Laravel dosen't see path to file with Custom Request Class, how to fix it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, namespaces, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I created Custom ReadRequest Class. Than I created folder with "Order" name in Requests folder, and put there my ReadRequest.php file:

[image]

After this manipulation Laravel doesn't see this file in my Controller:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you set the namespace?

Comment: @Hedam Yes, you can see it on the second image

Comment: No, the namespace is not in the second image. It's the `namespace` tag which I assume you are missing ;-)

Comment: @Hedam ohh, yes, I didn't change my name space in my ReadRequest.php file. I forget that I should do that . Oh :(

Comment: @Hedam I got used that IDE do all such little things automatically (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't written how you know that Laravel doesn't see this file but looking at your screen it seems your IDE doesn't see it it either. So make sure in your `ReadRequest.php` file you have

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Order;

class ReadRequest
{
  // ...
}
```

It's very possible that you have invalid classname in this file or invalid namespace, so your IDE shows you the error and also composer cannot load the file.

Comment: yes, I didn't change my name space in my ReadRequest.php file.